# Simply in .bat file in windows

Tags: batch-file

I created script for install files from network place. 
However, I need to fix inputs from command line.

```
set num=
set /p num=Enter your choose: 
if "%num%"=="1" goto installJabber
if "%num%"=="2" goto installTimer
if "%num%"=="3" goto installVMWare
if "%num%"=="4" goto installOffice
```

How do I write "if "%num"" is not 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 then exit ?

Comment: This is a very simple problem, please use Google to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....
if "%num%"=="4" goto installOffice
goto :eof
```

:eof is recognised by batch as meaning 'the end of the batch file'. The colon is required.

Comment: Why are you answering such a simple question? Googling "exit batch script" gives tons of solutions.